# A-Frame getObject3D('mesh') returns undefined with multiple tries

Tags: javascript, three.js, aframe

I am trying to get a bounding box for an obj-model in A-frame. I hereby will refer to these two useful links I have found on stackoverflow:
[How to get bounding box information from a 3D object in aframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49291812/how-to-get-bounding-box-information-from-a-3d-object-in-aframe?noredirect=1&lq=1)
[Any way to get a bounding box from a three.js Object3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492857/any-way-to-get-a-bounding-box-from-a-three-js-object3d)
But after I tried with those code below,

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('bounding-box', {
            init: function(){
                var el = this.el;
                var obj = el.getObject3D('mesh');
                console.log(obj);
                var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
                console.log(bbox.min, bbox.max);    
            }
        })
```

I got "undefined" from `console.log(obj);`, and then I tried the method that is mentioned in the above link,

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('bounding-box', {
    init: function(){
        var el = this.el;
        console.log(el);
        el.setAttribute('obj-model', {obj: 'obj5/1026/1026outside.obj'});
        var obj = el.getObject3D('mesh');
        console.log(obj);
        var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
        console.log(bbox.min, bbox.max);    
    }
})
```

But still with no luck. Only if I put the code just above the  closing tag, sometimes it works and log the correct information of the bounding box.

```
<script>
    var el = document.querySelector('#b-model');
    console.log(el);
    var obj = el.getObject3D('mesh');
    console.log(obj);

    var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
    console.log(bbox.min, bbox.max);    
</script>
</body>
```

I think it is related to loading sequence but I am not understanding the discussion in this post:
[How to load 3D object at runtime in aframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49269426/how-to-load-3d-object-at-runtime-in-aframe)
Like I tried above, this method is not working. Or maybe I used `el.setAttribute` in a wrong way? I also noticed that Felix said that using three.objLoader can solve the problem and I tried as well but still with no luck. I know in theory that the reason to register a component is because it executes only after the attached entity is initialized. So I am very confused here. Can anyone let me know how to do this by registering a component rather than a loose javascript at the end? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your model is loading properly, You probably are trying to get the  `mesh` (as well as the bounding box) before the model is loaded.

If you wait for the `model-loaded` event:

```
modelElement.addEventListener('model-loaded', (e) => {
  var obj = modelElement.getObject3D('mesh');
  var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
  console.log(bbox)
})
```

It should be working fine. Check it out on [this glitch](https://glitch.com/%7Eaframe-model-bbox), or [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/5epyjto1/), with a `gltf` model.

---

For primitives, you can just listen for the `loaded` event:

```html
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script>
  AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
    init: function() {
      this.el.addEventListener("loaded", (e) => {
        var obj = this.el.getObject3D('mesh');
        var bbox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(obj);
        const boxHelper = new THREE.Box3Helper(bbox, 0xff0000);
        this.el.object3D.add(boxHelper)
      })
    }
  })
</script>

<a-scene>
  <a-sphere foo color="blue" position="0 1 -4">  </a-sphere>
</a-scene>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved my problem. I have another maybe related question when I am working on another problem. Do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53277752/reflect-a-users-position-and-rotation-in-runtime-on-a-minimap-in-aframe

Comment: Using the `loaded` event worked for me. In my case, I was trying to get the object3D mesh from an `a-plane` entity.