# Reflect a user's position and rotation in runtime on a minimap in Aframe

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, aframe, webvr

I am trying to make a minimap for my vr scene and update the user's position and location in runtime. I already made the following:

```
<script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('cam-listener', {
            init: function(){
                var canvas = document.querySelector("#myCanvas");
                //line 124(log result in the image)
                console.log(canvas);
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                //line 126(log result in the image)
                console.log(context);

                function drawTriangle(x, y) {
                  // the triangle
                  context.beginPath();
                  context.moveTo(x, y);
                  context.lineTo(x - 6, y + 10);
                  context.lineTo(x + 6, y + 10);
                  context.closePath();

                  // the outline
                  context.lineWidth = 4;
                  context.strokeStyle = "rgba(102, 102, 102, 1)";
                  context.stroke();

                  // the fill color
                  context.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 204, 0, 1)";
                  context.fill();
                }
                drawTriangle(100, 100);
            }
            tick: function(){
                console.log(this.el.getAttribute('position'));
                console.log(document.querySelector('[camera]').getAttribute('rotation'));
            }
        })
 </script>
```

below is the div and canvas:

```
<div id="canvasWrapper">
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="223.99" height="358.93">
        </canvas>
</div>
```

but the thing is that when I run the script, the console gives me very confusing result:(below is the image link)

[canvas retrieved but context is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwn6Y.png)

but if I do not use Aframe component system and put the scripts bottom of the body, everything works. So does anyone know the reason? Thanks in advance!

BTW, if anyone know how to make a minimap in Aframe vr scene I am glad to discuss and learn. If not I will post my solution afterwards.

Comment: Try creating the canvas within the component, or grabbing it after a delay (e.g., on the `play` handler versus the `init` handler, or document loaded).

Comment: for the document loaded method, are you saying : `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
  // Handler when the DOM is fully loaded
});`?  and put all canvas parts in the function?@ngokevin

Comment: seems to be working as it is, check out [this](https://jsfiddle.net/6cx823rp/1/) fiddle.

Comment: Since I have much more contents in the scene, it did not work for me. @Piotr Adam Milewski. But thank you for testing it out. I tried with this `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){//draw on canvas})` but I never get the console logged anything. I do not know why. Maybe too many contents? My page loading timed out at 3000 BTW. But all 3d contents loaded in the end

Comment: Can you add a Glitch or JSFiddle?